# How to filter two columns using ui grid

Tags: jquery, filter, angular-ui-grid

I want to filter a column using greater than or less than combination as well as not between greater than and less than values

For example, in current filter conditions it works for greater than and less than condition. If i enter 73 in greater than and 85 in less than it shows the data, likewise i want it as if i type only 73 as greater than in the text it should show the data or else if i type only 85 in less than it should show the data. Same scenario for not condition, in short i need OR, NOT operation to be performed for filter conditions since already AND operation for filter is done in jquery.

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Physics</th>
      <th>Chemistry</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="6" placeholder="less than"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="6"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="6" placeholder="greater than"/></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>75</td>
      <td>86</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>68</td>
    <td>72</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>91</td>
    <td>96</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>86</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>76</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>84</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>69</td>
    <td>58</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>82</td>
    <td>76</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If i want to filter it should be as

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Physics</th>
      <th>Chemistry</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="73" size="6"/></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="85" size="6"/></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>84</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>82</td>
    <td>76</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying with this jquery code

```
filters : [ {
            condition : uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN,
            placeholder : 'less than'
        },
         {
            condition : uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN,
            placeholder : 'greater than'
        }
        ]
```

Comment: please create fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create condition function on your demand. You don't have to use filter functions in uiGridConstants.filter